# Order of mounting USB devices in Linux

Tags: linux, mount

I'm running a Ubuntu system where USB drives are mounted automatically.
I'm curious to what happens when a USB device plugs in a port. Which part of the linux senses that a new device has been plugged in? After that which processes (and what is the caller or callers) are called to mount it to the system? Are theese kernel-space, user-space processes or mixed ?

I'd like to follow theese steps in a C/C++ program. Is there any way to do that? Where could I read more about it? How would you do it?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [udev](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Udev) is a pretty good place for an overview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are several systems that can be used to react to a plugged-in USB device. One is `udev`, and this runs as root. You can put your own rules and scripts in `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Furthermore, the desktop environments all implement some automounting, see for example [this guide](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Automount). See also the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194707/what-happens-under-the-hood-when-an-usb-drive-is-inserted).